# Infinite loop when trying to read an int greater than INT_MAX

Tags: c++, iostream

I was writing some C++ code, to figure out the internal representation of integers. But I stumbled upon a weird bug, and I can't seem to reason about the cause of this issue.

The code is quite simple. it asks for a user input (I, LI, or SI).

LI and SI gives the representation of largest and smallest integers respectively. 'I' needs an integer input, whose representation the user wants to know.

Everything works perfect until I gave the input as,

I 2147483648

Now this is one greater than the largest integer in C++ (2147483647).

I expected the output to be 7FFFFFFF, which is the output for 2147483647 and ask for the next input.

But instead, this started an infinite loop, giving the output as:

7FFFFFFF 
7FFFFFFF 
7FFFFFFF 
...

What is the the cause of this infinite loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

const int intMax = numeric_limits<int>::max();
const int intMin = numeric_limits<int>::min();
int num;

void createMap(map<string, char> *um){

    (*um)["0000"] = '0';
    (*um)["0001"] = '1';
    (*um)["0010"] = '2';
    (*um)["0011"] = '3';
    (*um)["0100"] = '4';
    (*um)["0101"] = '5';
    (*um)["0110"] = '6';
    (*um)["0111"] = '7';
    (*um)["1000"] = '8';
    (*um)["1001"] = '9';
    (*um)["1010"] = 'A';
    (*um)["1011"] = 'B';
    (*um)["1100"] = 'C';
    (*um)["1101"] = 'D';
    (*um)["1110"] = 'E';
    (*um)["1111"] = 'F';
}

string convertBinToHex(string bin){

    int l = bin.size();
    map<string, char> bin_hex_map;
    createMap(&bin_hex_map);

    int i = 0;
    string hex = "";

    while(i < bin.size()){
        hex += bin_hex_map[bin.substr(i, 4)];
        i += 4;
    }
    return hex;
}

void printHex(int num){

    int *var_ptr;
    var_ptr = &num;
    string bin = "";

    for (int i=31; i>=0; i--) {
        bin += to_string((*var_ptr >> i) & 1);
    }
    // cout << bin << endl;
    cout << convertBinToHex(bin) << endl;
}

int main(){

    string input = "";
    cout << "Enter I or LI or SI or Q" << endl;
    // cin >> input;
    while(input != "Q"){
        cin >> input;
        if(input == "LI"){
            cout << intMax << " ";
            printHex(intMax);
        }
        else if(input == "SI"){
            cout << intMin << " ";
            printHex(intMin);
        }
        else if(input == "I"){
            cin >> num;
            printHex(num);
            // sleep(2);
            // cout << "What is going on ?" << endl;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not check if `cin` succeeded.

Comment: btw there is no "largest integer in C++" the size of `int` is at least 16 bits, but there is no upper bound, in practice of course there is but it depends on target platform

Comment: @idclev463035818 - to put it another way, ISO C++ *requires* every C++ implementation to set some finite fixed width and thus fixed upper limit on each integer type.  So a hypothetical C++ implementation couldn't have `int` that worked as a BigInteger like Python, growing without limit.  That's one factor that makes C++ not fully Turing complete, at least not easily; no equivalent of infinite tape.  Addresses and integers are required to have some finite width in any given implementation.

Comment: @PeterCordes interesting, I didn't know that. However, I guess also Pythons BigInteger has a finite limit on its size

Comment: @idclev463035818: In any practical implementation it does, but in the abstract language there's no set upper limit you can query.  A hypothetical Python running on a Turing machine could support infinite sized integers and infinite-length lists.  That's the key difference from a CS theory perspective.  It of course has zero practical relevance from an engineering POV.

Comment: @sabreload22: FYI, using a ordered map (typically red-black tree) from `string, char` is a hilariously inefficient way to parse base-2 input.  Converting a string of 4 base-2 digits to an `int` is cheaper, and then you can use it to simply index a `std::array<char, 16>`, or a plain `char hex_lookup_table[16]`.  Or `num + '0'` and check for `> '9'`, and if so add to put it in the `'a' .. 'f'` range.  Definitely cheaper than a tree search or hash table lookup!  And still avoids converting the whole base 2 input to `int`, since you're apparently avoid that to support arbitrary-length I guess?

Comment: @PeterCordes python can be implemented in c++, so one is as turing complete as the other, no? Anyhow, I do get your point.

Comment: @idclev463035818: A "normal" Python implementation can be written in C++.  A hypothetical one supporting truly unbounded integers couldn't be.  Both languages are Turing-complete in every respect except ability to use an unbounded amount of storage.  (C and C++ can possibly do that via I/O though, e.g. by seeking around in an unbounded file stream = infinite tape.)  See [Is C actually Turing-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60965) on cs.SE

Comment: @idclev463035818: Correction, I should have said "unbounded" not "infinite" in every previous comment.  As [@Gilles points out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55209375#55209375), that's an important distinction.  For any given program, there's enough memory for the machine to run it, however much that is.

Comment: @sabreload22: Also, your question title doesn't reflect the question body.  Integer representation is required by the ISO C++ standard to be 2's complement, 1's complement, or sign/magnitude.  (Or in C++20, only 2's complement).  You can examine the object-representation or other objects using `unsigned char*` which ISO C++ guarantees has no padding bits. Or you can look at the compiler's asm output for a given implementation.  But your question body is about a bug in your iostream input loop, nothing to do with integer representation.  I edited to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the integer representation. It's that the conversion of the input fails, which means it will still be left in the input buffer, leading to your infinite loop reading the exact same data over and over again.

You need to check if the input succeeded or not, and if it failed you need to clear the buffer as well as the error flags:

```
if (!(cin >> num))
{
    // Error, failed to parse the input

    // First clear the error status flags
    cin.clear();

    // Then remove the current line of input from the buffer
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
else
{
    // Input okay, use it...
}
```

Since it's a lot to write for each input, I suggest you move it out to a function that you call to get input.